# peer to peer connection to a computer in external network using python socket library

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to create a peer-to-peer python app using the socket library. I am curious to know if there is any way in which I can use the socket library to connect to another computer outside my local network without any manual steps like opening ports on the router for port forwarding. Do I need to use an already open port on the router (given that routers have some ports open on default)? Please guide me. I am new to socket and networking.

My code till now:-

client-1 (sender)

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((MYPUBLICIP, 433))
s.send(b"HELLO!")
s.close()
```

client 2 (receiver)

```py
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((MYPRIVATEIP, 433))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"[CONNECTION_ALERT] Received connection request from {addr}.")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1026).decode('utf-8')
            if not data:
                break
            print(data)
```

The error I am getting:

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

If needed, my python version is 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution to connect two hosts on the same local network

Error message suggest that your firewall probably blocked the network traffic, you can try to disable your firewall and try again, but it is not advisable. If you want to play with network stuff i would suggest you create a local lab that is not connected to internet, like VM's or old laptops/pc.

### Solution to connect two hosts NOT on the same local network

If you want to connect two hosts that are not on the same local network then the problem becomes more complicated, and have several possible solutions:

- Ask your ISP for public IP (easy but usually comes with extra costs)
- Use available software solutions to create private networks over the internet, like [hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) (also easy but depending on the usecase cost will vary)
- *Exploiting* naive NAT's by using [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) (hard to implement but satisfying if done right, nice explanation of how it was implemented in [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/news/2021/09/26/new-multiplayer-experience) multiplayer)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my query is if there is any way to automate the process of opening a port on the router, utilizing an already open port on the router or anything as such so that I will be able to establish a socket connection between 2 computers on a different network

Comment: If you want a solution that doesn't relays on opening of ports it's tricky but possible. Routers usually allows for outbound traffic and disallow inbound traffic, unless it is a response to request send from local network. You can *exploit* this for your use but it is not something trivial, you can research into [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN). There is also nice, somewhat easy explanation how it was implemented in [OpenTTD](https://www.openttd.org/news/2021/09/26/new-multiplayer-experience)

Comment: You could also just create virtual connections between hosts using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), or [hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/). This again removes the need to open routers ports and walk around NAT limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I shall look into them. However, I am interested to know if there are there any ports open by default on the router of an average internet user that I can just use to establish a connection?

Comment: It depends on your ISP you should ask them, but usually the answer is sadly none.

Comment: Is it possible to open a port on the router using a script? Sorry if I am aking too much

Comment: It again depends on your router, usually you can only access the administrator panel from web interface, but sometimes it is also possible to open an ssh or telnet session. But i would first check if manually opening ports will solve your problems, because it probably won't as the network traffic will be rejected by your ISP NAT regardless.

Comment: Thank you so much. Please edit your answer with the points mentioned in the comments and I shall select it as the answer